# Is this equation for transconductance correct?

Tags: input-impedance

\$\frac{1}{g_m} = \frac{r_\pi}{(1+\beta)}\$

Is this equation correct? If so, how are they equivalent?

In words: inverse of the transconductance = \$\frac{r_\pi}{(1+\beta)}\$

[image: Small-Signal model]

Comment: You should be able to write beta using LaTeX format, `\$ \beta \$` produces \$ \beta \$

Comment: Sincere apologies, have never used LaTex. Should be learning it soon

Comment: No worries, just makes writing equations easier on stack exchange

Comment: Yep that's the correct format. Still confused on how they equal...

Comment: It is not correct for a MOSFET. It is not correct for a relay. It might be correct for some other device. Did you have a particular one in mind?

Answer (score -1):

I suppose, we are speaking about bipolar transistors, right?
The following definitions apply:

- Transconductance (slope of the Ic=f(Vbe) function): gm=d(Ic)/d(Vbe)
- Input resistance (inverse slope of the Ib=f(Vbe) function): rbe=d(Vbe)/d(Ib)
- From this: **gm=d(Ic)/[d(Ib)rbe]=beta/rbe**.

Comment: Okay. Is rbe the equivalent to r(pi) or they totally different things?

Comment: The quantity rbe is the actual base-emitter resistance. Can you explain the meaning of r(pi)?

Comment: Please see image. r(pi) being the resistance seen at the base terminal

Comment: -1 for not using the math markup that we gave OP a hard time for not using. Please clean up your formulae and the downvote will be reversed.

Comment: I don`t care about your downvoting. It seems that you have not understood my answer - I have given the DEFINITION of all the terms I have used. More than that, perhaps you did not notice that the OP has shown his diagram only AFTER my answer. That means: He has used r(pi) WITHOUT definition. It seems that you do not know that the use of rbe is more correct than using r(pi).

Comment: Adam Lawrence, what about YOUR reply to the OPs question ? (Instead of criticizing other answers).